# Which one is the right sentence here?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Assume that John is taking interview of harry. In past, harry was an administrator but now he is not . what should harry say here?

**JOHN** : Harry, Tell me about your past experience

**Harry** : I was an administrator for two years at COMPANY A

Or

**Harry** : I have been an administrator for two years at COMPANY A

I think they are just like "I did that for two years" and "i have done that for two years" But both refer to Past. But "I have done that for two years" sounds More accurate when we want to describe any time period (for,since). So i am thinking 2nd one is more accurate here.

Answer (score 1):

"I was an administrator for two years at COMPANY A" clearly implies that you are no longer an administrator there.   "I have been an administrator for two years at COMPANY A" has a soft implication that you are still an administrator there.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, note that you were either *in admin* (i.e. administration) or *an administrator*. You cannot be *an admin* (unless this is company slang for an administrator).

The third sentence is the correct way of saying that at some stage of your career, you spent two years in admin. It gives no indication of when you were there. It simply states that you (have) acquired two years' experience in administration.

The first sentence states that you have spent the past two years in admin. At this point you have completed two years in admin.

The second sentence would be used in a construction in which you make it clear that you had completed your two years in admin before doing something else.

> > I stated that *I had been in admin for two years* before I was appointed as a senior manager.

Note the three time references. First you were in admin, then you were appointed as a senior manager and finally you stated this.

Otherwise you might say:

> > I was in admin for two years before I was appointed a senior manager.

Comment: You can absolutely be an admin as in "administrator." That's perfectly normal slang.

Comment: Hey ronald,Thanks for your answer But i was referring to administrator . So is it correct . "I was an administrator for 2 years" And i updated my question please take a look.

Comment: @PhillipLongman I live and learn.

Comment: @beginner The same rules apply. If you say *I have been", it implies that you still are. If you say *I was*, it means that at some point in the past you were.

Comment: @RonaldSole Your explanation in the comment is correct.  I don't know if this is because of edits to the question, but it looks like the ordering of the sentences you're referring to is off, or at least hard to follow.  It would help to refer to the sentences by quoting them instead of using "first sentence," "second sentence," etc.  But the point you made is correct, *have been* implies *still are*.   *I was* means *at some point was*.

Comment: "To begin, note that you were either in admin (i.e. administration) or an administrator. You cannot be an admin (unless this is company slang for an administrator).", I can't understand what you are saying.